# cast away const/volatile from a pointer or reference

Tags: c++, lint

This is a part of my code ...
As I know the casting is proper as I have done below, but I am getting the linting warning for my logic..                                                                                                               Can You explain it why it is like this ..
Part of my code :

```
typedef struct
{
    char  appid[4];                  /**< application id */
    int32 pid;                      /**< process id of user application */
} DApplication;

static int32 d_cmp(const void *m1, const void *m2)
{
    DApplication *mi1 = (DApplication *) m1;   //Line 1
    DApplication *mi2 = (DApplication *) m2;   //Line 2
    return memcmp(mi1->appid, mi2->appid, 4);  //Line 3
}

And warnings are :                      
Sample.cpp (line 1):Note 960: Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 11.5, attempt to cast away const/volatile from a pointer or reference
Sample.cpp (line 2):Note 960: Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 11.5, attempt to cast away const/volatile from a pointer or reference
Sample.cpp (line 3):Note 960: Violates MISRA 2004 Required Rule 10.1, Implicit conversion changes signedness

...Courtsey MISRA
As per the MISRA rule :                                              Rule 11.5 (required): A cast shall not be performed that removes any const or volatile
qualification from the type addressed by a pointer.
[Undefined 39, 40]
Any attempt to remove the qualification associated with the addressed type by using casting is a
violation of the principle of type qualification. Notice that the qualification referred to here is not
the same as any qualification that may be applied to the pointer itself.

uint16_t x;
uint16_t * const cpi = &x; /* const pointer */
uint16_t * const * pcpi; /* pointer to const pointer */
const uint16_t * * ppci; /* pointer to pointer to const */
uint16_t * * ppi;
const uint16_t * pci; /* pointer to const */
volatile uint16_t * pvi; /* pointer to volatile */
uint16_t * pi;
...
pi = cpi; /* Compliant - no conversion
no cast required */
pi = (uint16_t *)pci; /* Not compliant */
pi = (uint16_t *)pvi; /* Not compliant */
ppi = (uint16_t * *)pcpi; /* Not compliant */
ppi = (uint16_t * *)ppci; /* Not compliant */                        

SO According to this rule i think it is fine
```

Comment: Why do you think the casting is proper? You are casting away `const`.

Comment: `void*` it's not really a `C++` =)

Comment: Then what would be the correct way of casting this ??

Comment: Casting would be `const DApplication *mi1 = reinterpret_cast<const DApplication*> m1;`. But this is still not correct C++.

Comment: @Ashwin If you are sure that `m1` and `m2` actually point to non-const objects, you should specify the function arguments as `void *`, not `const void *`. And, another big question of course is why you use `void` at all... (but that's not related to the constness problem).

Comment: As per the MISRA rule :

Comment: @Drop: that's why the C++ compiler will refuse to compile it, right?  There's no point saying stuff isn't C++ when it's provided for in the Standard....

Comment: @TonyD not all code that compiles is correct =)

Answer (score 2):

It is like this because you are playing with fire.  You are not using the type system, you are circumventing it.  There are much better ways to do this in C++, such as:

```
static int32 d_cmp(const DApplication *m1, const DApplication *m2)
```

or

```
const DApplication *mi1 = static_cast<const DApplication *>(m1);
```

Answer (score 2):

> As I know the casting is proper as I have done below...

Why do you think your casting is "proper"?  You have `const` parameters and you're removing the `const`-ness from them for no good reason at all.  What's the type of `memcmp()` parameters on your system?  They should be `const` pointers - from http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/memcmp

```
int memcmp( const void* lhs, const void* rhs, std::size_t count );
```

So, you can fix your function like this:

```
static int32 d_cmp(const void* m1, const void* m2)
{
    return memcmp(static_cast<const DApplication*>(m1)->appid,
                  static_cast<const DApplication*>(m2)->appid,
                  sizeof DApplication().appid);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are casting away the constness. You don't need to do that in anyway if you are just gonna use memcmp since it takes `(const void*, const void*, size_t)`.

Try this:

```
#include <cstring> // memcmp

typedef struct {
    char appid[4];                /**< application id */
    int pid;                      /**< process id of user application */
} DApplication;

static int d_cmp(const void *m1, const void *m2)
{
    const DApplication *mi1 = static_cast<const DApplication *>(m1);   //Line 1
    const DApplication *mi2 = static_cast<const DApplication *>(m2);   //Line 2
    return memcmp(mi1->appid, mi2->appid, 4);  //Line 3
}

int main(void)
{
    DApplication a1 = {{0,0,0,0}, 1};
    DApplication a2 = {{0,0,0,1}, 1};

    return d_cmp(&a1, &a2);
}
```

Remember to compile it with a c++ compiler (use `g++` and not `gcc`).

Comment: When I am trying with the same statement it is showing syntax error ..what is missing ..

Comment: The only difference with an old fashion cast is that const is respected. This means that a reinterpret_cast can not be used to cast a const object to non-const object.                      http://www.codingunit.com/c-tutorial-typecasting-part-1               Am geeting below error :                                              Multiple markers at one line                                                  Missing ;                                                                  Syntax Error

Comment: There, added the complete example.

Answer (score 0):

As question is tagged `C++` here is somewhat more like C++ solution.

This solution, solves problem by **eliminating casting**, and also makes code cleaner, safer and, probably, faster.

1. You can use anonymous namespace instead of `static`.
2. You can use function template to keep type safety (if you'll need diffrent types at all. If not, just hard-code `DApplication`).
3. No need to use pointers. Use references instead.
4. Use [`std::array`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array) instead of C-style array. It provides [`operator==()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/array/operator_cmp) for convenient (and, more likely, faster) element-wise comparison, so no need to `memcmp`.

   ```
   struct DApplication
   {
       std::array <char, 4> appid;
       int pid;
   };

   struct NotDApplication
   {
       int foo;
   };

   namespace {
       template <typename T>
       bool CompareAppIds(const T& mi1, const T& mi2)
       {
           return (mi1.appid == mi2.appid);
       }
   }

   int main()
   {
       DApplication a, b;
       NotDApplication c, d;

       bool isEqual = CompareAppIds(a, b);  // OK

       bool isEqual2 = CompareAppIds(c, d); // Compile error: 
                                            // 'appid' : is not a member
                                            // of 'NotDApplication'
   }
   ```
5. Also, you can overload `operator==()` for `DApplication` if suitable.